# Formula to calculate item probability of being sampled with weights and without replacement

Tags: r, probability

I'm struggling to translate [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/320640/79518) into a working R function.

I have a population $V$ of $n$ weighted items. I want a sample $S$ of size $m$ selected by weighted random sampling. How do I define the probability of each item being sampled?

```
V = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")

W = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.25, 0.2)

m = 4

S = sample(V, m, W, replace = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

calculate the probabilities of all possible combination of letters(addition of all the permutation of each set of 4 letters).

Then add all the probabilities of all the cases for each letter appears in the set.

if you just want to get a distribution or statistics. I would do simulations and get the numbers rather than actually calculate it.